# CSS-Only Menu Help Needed

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I would like to add a CSS-only drop down menu to a site. I am able to do this with just one drop, but am having trouble with adding another tier to the menu.

I am able to get the list to hide initially, but when the trigger is hovered over, the entire list becomes visible, instead of just the first tier of the drop down list.

This is part of the list:

```
 <ul id="DealerNav">
<li><a href="#" class="first">Order from your dealer</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">BFC Syringe (empty)</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.atlantadental.com" target="_blank">Atlanta Dental</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.benco.com" target="_blank">Benco Dental</a></li> 
       </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">BFC Complete</a>
          <ul>
          <li><a href="http://practicon.com/Harmony-Intro-Pack/p/70-90122/" target="_blank">Practicon Dental</a></li>
          </ul>
             </li>
    <li><a href="#">Vaccu•sil Heavy Body</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.atlantadental.com" target="_blank">Atlanta Dental</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.benco.com" target="_blank">Benco Dental</a></li> 
             <li><a href="http://www.burkhartdental.com" target="_blank">Burkhart Dental</a></li>

       </ul> 
    </li>      
  </ul>
```

And, this is the CSS that controls it:

```
#DealerNav { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-weight: bold; }

#DealerNav li { list-style-type: none; font-size: 100%; position: relative; margin-left: -3em; }

#DealerNav li li { margin: 2px 0; }

#DealerNav li ul { display: none; }

#DealerNav a.first { width:100%; color: #555; background-color: #FFF; margin-left: 2.5em; }

#DealerNav a { display:block; width: 12em; padding: .5em; background-color: #CEF; color: #FFF;  }

#DealerNav a:hover { color: #555; }

#DealerNav a:hover.first { color: #CEF; }

#DealerNav li:hover ul { display: block; }

#DealerNav ul ul { margin-left:10em; margin-top: -2.25em; }
```

Is this too complicated to ask help on?

The page in question is temporarily at:
http://www.hodentalcompany.com/pages/syringe2.html

The menu is at the bottom of the right column on the text, "Order from your dealer"

Thanks everyone for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
#DealerNav li:hover ul { display: block;}
```

to this:

```
#DealerNav li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

You only want the first child UL to show, not all of them.,

Comment: That's good, except the menu disappears after I move past the first item in the first child list. Also, there is a big gap between the first item in the list and the second. So, maybe I had better start over and create it like the suggestion on jsfiddle...

Comment: Rule #1: Other than float, position and display, put all styling on the A-tag (with display:block), not on the LI.

Comment: I hate to ask, but I have one last problem...

I put all the styling on the anchor tags except an initial margin and padding reset on the nav div to get the first position to the main text correct (couldn't figure out another way). That took care of the menu disappearing. Thank you!

Problem now is that the last menu list (third list) only shows the last item. (Not even the first, but the last!)

Comment: Code now:

#DealerNav { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#DealerNav li { list-style-type: none; position: relative; }
#DealerNav li ul { display: none; }
#DealerNav a.first { width:100%; font-size: 100%;font-weight: bold; color: #54ABDF; background-color: #FFF; margin-left:-.5em; }
#DealerNav a { display:block; font-size: 90%; width: 12em; padding: .5em; margin: 2px 0; background-color: #54ABDF; color: #FFF;  }
#DealerNav a:hover { color: #555; }
#DealerNav a:hover.first { color: #38B; }
#DealerNav li li a { margin-left:-3.25em; }
#DealerNav li:hover > ul { display: block; }

Comment: Last line:
#DealerNav ul ul a { margin-left:6.45em; margin-top: -2.25em; }

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/